# Show that $\phi(K)=KN/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Let $N\triangleleft G$ and $K\leqslant G$. Consider $\phi :G \mapsto G/N$ onto group homomorphism. Show that $\phi(K)=KN/N$.

I thought using the equality $(G/N)^{n}=G^{n}N/N$ to show but I can not show. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $gN \in \phi(K)$, then there exists $k \in K$ such that $gN = kN$ $\implies$ $k^{-1}g=n$ for some $n \in N$. So $kn=g$. Thus $gN = knN \in KN/N$. So $\phi(K) \subseteq KN/N$. Now suppose $x \in KN/N$ then $x=knN$ for some $k\in K, n \in N$ $\implies$ $x=knN=kN$ as $n \in N$ So $x \in \phi(K)$. So $ KN/N  \subseteq \phi(K)$. Combining both we get our result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show it’s a subset and it covers everything. Both are straightforward ($knN=kN$ and any $knN$ has rep $kn$ is in the image of $k$. )

Clarification based on comments:$KN$ is the set of all elements $kn$ for $k$ in $K$ and $n$ in $N$. $KN/N$ is just the cosets of elements in $KN$. You don’t need that $N$ is normal for this to be true - that’s needed later to show nice things like that this is a group homomorphism. The key idea is that $\phi(k)=kN$ and $k=ke$ is in $KN$, so $\phi$ maps into $KN/N$. Then for the reverse, any closet is of the form $knN$, so it equals $\phi(k)$, so it’s in the image.

Comment: more than a subset, he has to prove it's actually a subgroup (which comes from $N$ being normal)

Comment: @Evariste that's not true, showing it is a subset is enough.

Comment: @KentaS If you say so. It wasn't obvious to me that $KN$ is actually a subgroup of $G$ (it wouldn't be the case if $N$ were not normal a priori)

Comment: @Evariste Although true, whether $KN$ is a subgroup of $G$ or not is irrelevant here. We only need to find the set-theoretic image of $K$ under $\phi$.

Comment: @KentaS How would you define the quotient by $N$ if $KN$ were not a group?

Comment: @Evariste the standard definition would be $KN/N:=\{gN:g\in KN\}$.

Comment: I really confused right now. ( I am bad at algebra btw )

Comment: Sorry @softglance, we are arguing over a very minute detail. Eric's response should suffice.

Comment: I think I agree with @KentaS. It might well be true that  $KN/N$ is being used to denote a group here rather than just a set, but even if that is true, then the question is implicitly assuming that it is a group, and the exercise does not require you to prove that it is a group. (This may seem to be a very trivial and pedantic point, but this kind of issue arises a lot when grading exams. The convention in exams has to be that students are not required to do anything unless they are specifically asked to.)

Comment: I added clarification to the answer. That $KN/N$ Is a group is independent of this question (and I’d guess a prior question in the exam/textbook).